# Google API in Rails is too slow

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-api, ruby-on-rails-4

All operations using google-api-client are too slow in my rails app.

- Ruby: 1.9.3
- Rails: 4.0.0
- Gem: google-api-client
- OS: Debian
- Hosting: DigitalOcean 1GB RAM (it is almost equally slow on my local machine)
- Mode: Development (it is almost equally slow in production mode)
- Load time: 8 - 11 seconds

  ```
  def google_auth
      require 'google/api_client'

      client = Google::APIClient.new

      plus = client.discovered_api('oauth2')

      client.authorization.client_id = 'xxx'        
      client.authorization.client_secret = 'xx'
      client.authorization.redirect_uri = 'http://xxx'   
      client.authorization.scope = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"]

      client.authorization.code = params[:code]
      token = client.authorization.fetch_access_token!

      result = client.execute(
          :api_method => plus.userinfo.get
      )
  end
  ```

It takes about 10 seconds to process this simple method. No error/warning. Only methods with Google API calls are slow. Where is the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see the [Stack Overflow Newbie Manual](http://grahn.us/projects/stack-overflow.php?name=itrinity)!

Please add more information on your setup, load times for pages, what you are trying to do, any information that could help!

Comment: true! it does seem awfully slow. i think that NodeJS is what they want you to use these days.